# Как заменить сразу несколько символов в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

Есть некая строка:

```
s = ['This, is? a! string.']
```

Мне нужно заменить все знаки препинания в этой строке на пробелы. Конечно, можно сделать так:

```
s = s.replace('.', ' ')
s = s.replace(',', ' ')
s = s.replace('!', ' ')
s = s.replace('?', ' ')
```

Но ведь, наверное, существует более краткий способ сделать это?

**P. S.** Хотелось бы увидеть также изящные решения с помощью стандартных модулей (например, через регулярки).

Comment: А разве `replace` сам не заменяет всё сам?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard, в каком смысле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import re

s = 'This, is? a! string.'
new_s = re.sub(r"[,?!.]", " ", s)
```

Результат:

```
'This  is  a  string '
```

Answer (score 2):

### Первый способ (без использования регулярных выражений):

```py
import string

s = "This, is? a! string."


def replace_punctuation1(text):
    for char in text:
        if char in string.punctuation:
            text = text.replace(char, " ")
    return text


print(replace_punctuation1(s))  # This  is  a  string
```

### Второй способ (с "регуляркой"):

```py
import re


def replace_punctuation2(text):
    return re.sub(r"[^\w]", " ", text)


s = "This, is? a! string."

print(replace_punctuation2(s))  # This  is  a  string
```